# Could not load JDBC driver class - Spring Batch standalone program

Tags: java, spring, maven, jdbc, spring-batch

I'm working on a Spring Batch program, running it as a command-line app (currently via STS for testing).  When I run it via the Eclipse run/debug configuration via the org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner, it cannot load the SQL Server JDBC driver.  I'm certain I have it on the classpath, but evidently it is still having issues.

Here is my exception trace from the console log:

```
09:11:59.291 [main] ERROR o.s.b.c.l.s.CommandLineJobRunner - Job Terminated in error: Error creating bean with name 'legacyDatasource' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/module-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'legacyDatasource' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/module-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1506) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:290) [spring-batch-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:590) [spring-batch-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:3.0.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException: Failed properties: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:121) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1502) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

My datasource config from the spring xml (details changed to protect the innocent of course):

```
<bean id="legacyDatasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://server:1433;DatabaseName=database" />
  <property name="username" value="user" />
  <property name="password" value="pw" />
</bean>
```

Now to the classpath stuff...installed in my local maven repo:

[image]

And in my pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
  <artifactId>sqljdbc41</artifactId>
  <version>4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And it's in my project's Maven Dependencies:

[image]

In my run config, I've tried adding it directly to the classpath on the classpath tab, and through the VM argument.

[image]

I'm pretty sure it's something simple.  Any ideas why the driver cannot be loaded?  To me it's also worth noting that it's not a class not found error (though it may be under the covers and not part of this stack trace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had jdbc & sqlserver transposed in the package name.

```
<bean id="legacyDatasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://server:1433;DatabaseName=database" />
  <property name="username" value="user" />
  <property name="password" value="pw" />
</bean>
```